# Xbox Smartglass does not install for another user

Tags: google-play-store, nexus-7, 4.2-jelly-bean

I installed Xbox Smartglass from Google Play for one user. Afterwards, I tried to install it for another user, but I got this error:

> you cannot install this app because another user has already installed
>   an incompatible version on this device

The installed version is 1.0. How can I install for more than one user?

Comment: Where did you install Smartglass from? From Google Play, or an external APK file?

Comment: @geff From Google Play

Comment: So, you have installed Smartglass on your phone, and you want to install it again on the same phone? That's not possible. You can only install an app only once, or update it if there are updates.

Comment: @geff I did that some times and just did it again. Once for each user.

Comment: @geff_chang I believe Clodoaldo is referring to the multi-user support that exists in 4.2. This is a tablet, so it supports multi-user.

Answer (score 1):

Some apps cannot install for multiple users. Searching the developer forums, the only suggested solution is to contact the app developer (Microsoft) and ask them to test and enable multi-user support.

Technically, it is likely only a small issue like hard-coding where user-data should be stored and accessed instead of using the system provided path variables. Very trivial to fix once the developer is aware of the issue. If the app as open-source you could probably have done it yourself.